# Zero-initializing elements of a std::array with a default member initializer

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose I have a class template like this:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct S {
   std::array<T,N> a;
};
```

Is there a default member initializer I can place on `a`,

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct S {
   std::array<T,N> a = ???;
};
```

such that no matter what `T` is, the elements of `a` will always be initialized (never have indeterminant value)? I.e., even if `T` is a primitive type like `int`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct S {
   std::array<T,N> a = {};
};
```

That will recursively [copy-initialize each element from `{}`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#5.2). For `int`, that will zero-initialize. Of course, someone can always write:

```
struct A {
    A() {}
    int i;
};
```

which would prevent `i` from being initialized. But that's on them.

Answer (score 8):

`std::array` is an aggregate type. You can aggregate initialize it with empty braces `{}` and that will initialize accordingly the elements of the internal array of `T` that `std::array` holds.